# Up next widget GONE

Tags: ios

In iOS 13 there was an Up next widget, to show upcomming calendar appointments, reminders and alarms I think. This seems to be gone in iOS 14. I realize that there is a calendar widget, but that shows only calendar appointments. Reminders also comes with its own widget, but since it doesn't priotitize reminders that are due next it isn't all that useful. And even if, I would prefer to have it all in one place instead of having two widgets on the home screen.

Did Apple remove the Up next widget? Or haven't I looked deep enough?

Is there a way to communicate to Apple that I liked the Up next widget and that I would like to have it back?

Answer (score 1):

Apple removed that widget in iOS 14.

They introduced new options for the home screen and evidently felt that the popular widget was no longer necessary.

You can provide feedback to Apple via [their Feedback form](https://www.apple.com/feedback/iphone.html).